# Cannot find syntax errors in simple Python code

Tags: python

I do not understand why it does not run, I have all day trying to fix it. The program is supposed to be used to calculate the level of punctuation, and I no longer know what to do.

```
 bonificacion = 2400
    inaceptable = 0.1
    aceptable = 0.4
    meritorio = 0.6
    puntos = float(input("Introduce tu puntuacion: ")
    if puntos == inaceptable
        nivel = Inaceptable
                   print(nivel)
    elif puntos == aceptable
        nivel = Aceptable
                    print(nivel)
    elif puntos == meritorio
        nivel == Meritorio
                    print(nivel)
    else:
        nivel = ""
        #Mostrar nivel de rendimiento
    if nivel = "":
        print("Esta puntuacion no es valida")
    else:
        print("Tu nivel de rendimiento es %" nivel):
            print("Te corresponde cobrar %" puntos * bonificacion)
```

Comment: In the future, your question's title should reflect its content and topic.

Comment: Hola Javier, your code has so many syntax errors, I'm surprised the syntax highlighter even detected it as Python code. :-) Please let us know what error message you see.

Comment: Invalid syntax indeed... I just dont know how to fix it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to copy/paste the exact error message you got when running your code. Also, please reformat your code so it looks exactly like it does on your computer: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Granted, the question was not asked well and still lacks a proper title and such. But it's obviously asked by someone who seems to have never worked with Python before and just needed some help, so why downvote instead of providing assistance? Especially when the issue is so obvious and easy to address. Seriously, who needs the exact error message when looking at this code mess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (assuming some recent Python for f-strings).

Notes:

- I compare strings instead of floats, which often calls for trouble.
- Learn the difference between `=` (assignment) and `==` (comparison)
- `if` expressions must always be ended with colon `:`
- This code is not elegant but does the job and might best help you understand the flow (more streamlined version below)

```
bonificacion = 2400
inaceptable = '0.1'
aceptable = '0.4'
meritorio = '0.6'

puntos = input("Introduce tu puntuacion: ")
if puntos == inaceptable:
    nivel = 'inaceptable'
    print(nivel)
elif puntos == aceptable:
    nivel = 'aceptable'
    print(nivel)
elif puntos == meritorio:
    nivel = 'meritorio'
    print(nivel)
else:
    nivel = ""

# Show performance level
if nivel == "":
    print("Esta puntuación no es válida")
else:
    print(f"Tu nivel de rendimiento es {nivel}")
    print(f"Te corresponde cobrar {float(puntos) * bonificacion}")
```

**Update: A shorter version using a dict to map points to levels**

```
bonificacion = 2400

levels = {
    '0.1': 'inaceptable',
    '0.4': 'aceptable',
    '0.6': 'meritorio',
}

puntos = input("Introduce tu puntuacion: ")
nivel = levels.get(puntos, "")

# Show performance level
if nivel == "":
    print("Esta puntuación no es válida")
else:
    print(f"Tu nivel de rendimiento es {nivel}")
    print(f"Te corresponde cobrar {float(puntos) * bonificacion}")
```

Comment: Wow! It did work, i couldnt be more grateful! Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, python uses whitespace to denote blocks, this means that indentation matters. In your code the lines after the first are indented to the right, which will give a `IndentationError: unexpected indent`